# Add chosen after adding id by dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am showing option with chosen plugin and latter add option to it.

I am trying below

```
<select id='one'>
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
</select>
```

and calling chosen plugin

```
$('#one').chosen();
```

it working fine now i am remove chosen part and adding new option to select box

```
$('#one').append(' <option>g</option>');
$('#one').addClass('abc').attr('id', '');
$('#one_chosen').remove();
$('.abc').attr('id', 'myid');
$('#myid').chosen();
```

as you can see that i have added id by class and calling chosen() on it but this time its not working. And i can not keep id one in select box if there is no chosen

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pcb4qajr/)

Comment: I'm confused. Your code appears to work, and it's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I dont see any problem on the fiddle

Comment: just updated fiddle, i dont even see chosen select box in it

Comment: because id should be unique.you should have id as a unique to avoid something bad that might happened

Comment: @Pekka id is unique there, i am removing id `#one` and adding `#myid` and calling on it

Comment: just remove first line,http://jsfiddle.net/qubkhtsc/1/

Comment: why do you remove $('#one_chosen') ? You want to update the options?

Comment: Not sure  if I follow your issue exactly. Can you rephrase he issue?

Comment: By using Chosen, it will hide the existing dom element and it will create a new one with id='id_chosen'. You can remove the chosen by id and make the old dom element display=inline.

Comment: `$('#one_chosen').remove();` should this be `$('#one').remove();`? since your id is `one`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qubkhtsc/3/

Comment: @thanks everyone ... i am getting chosen but not option i have appended to select box

Comment: check matei answer it could be it@Richerdfuld

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must clone the element in order to make it work:

```
$('#one').chosen();

$('#one').find('option:first').remove();

$myid = $('#one').clone().attr('id', 'myid').insertBefore('#one');

$("#one, #one_chosen").remove();

$myid.show().chosen();
```

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qubkhtsc/5/)

Comment: Probably the plugin has some internal variables which are not updated when you modify the same element

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure i understand your question. But you can refresh `chosen` with `.trigger("chosen:updated");` i.e you can do something like

```
 $('.select-chosen').chosen();
 $('#one').addClass('abc').attr('id', '');

 $('.abc').attr('id', 'myid');

 $('.select-chosen').trigger("chosen:updated");
```

## Update:

Ideally, if you want to fully change the `select chosen`, it is better to just hide and show new `select chosen`.  In case, if you want to `add` or `remove` option from select and want to gain fully functionality of chosen you can do it easily with

```
// add custom option
$(".select-chosen").append('<option>Custom Option</option>');

// remove existing option
$(".select-chosen option[value='a']").remove();
```

Refer : http://jsfiddle.net/qubkhtsc/5/